# Improving performance on Arm64 virtualization

Tags: qemu

I'm virtualizing an arm64 machine on my x64 system using this command:

```
"C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-aarch64.exe" 
-name "Windows on ARM64" 
-M virt,virtualization=true 
-cpu cortex-a72 
-smp 6 
-m 4G 
-bios QEMU_EFI.img 
-accel tcg,thread=multi 
-device VGA 
-device ramfb 
-device ich9-usb-ehci1 
-device nec-usb-xhci 
-device usb-kbd 
-device usb-mouse 
-nic user,model=virtio 
-device usb-storage,drive=moredrivers 
-drive if=none,id=moredrivers,media=cdrom,file=.\virtio-win-0.1.208.iso 
-device usb-storage,drive=drivers 
-drive if=none,id=drivers,readonly=on,file=.\drivers.vhdx 
-device usb-storage,drive=system 
-drive if=none,id=system,format=raw,file=.\system.vhdx
```

It runs really slowly, the processor having 1Ghz available on all 6 cores, going 100% all times.
Is there any way to increase performance?

Comment: There's probably ways to improve the disk performance (USB isn't going to be the fastest way to provide a block device I suspect) and the graphics performance (using virtio-gpu so the guest has an actual 3D-capable device), but for the CPU, there isn't really anything beyond "use a faster host CPU". It's emulation, emulation is not generally very fast.